# How to temporarily change file encoding?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, encoding

I'm using a plugin which can show the minimap for the file I'm editing. The plugin can only works with `utf-8`. Does anyone know how to dynamically/temporarily change the encoding in Vim, so I can make the minimap work by temporarily set the encoding to utf8?

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why not just use UTF-8 all the time?

Comment: Which encoding are you using? You can try to set the locale environment variables to match the file encoding, for example `export LANG=zh_CN.big5` or `export LANG=zh_CN.gb18030`. Also consider filing a GitHub issue to the authors of code-minimap and minimap.vim to properly detect the file encoding from Vim and respect it while generating the minimap. (It might help to give them a small example file they can test it on.)

Comment: Not sure whether this fits your definition of "temporary" but you could simply `:set fileencoding=utf-8`, save the file, and then set it back again when you're done.

Comment: @Rich: Yes it fits, you might write an answer If you're willing to. I was thinking about whether there is a way to set a fallback option, say that it will first try `big5` if it cannot display all text then try `utf-8`.

Comment: @job_start Yes, that's possible. The reason I haven't actually gotten around to answering your question is that I was a bit unclear on your actual requirements I'll try writing something now.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the encoding of a loaded buffer simply by setting [`'fileencoding'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27fileencoding%27) and then saving the file:

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:w
```

Hopefully this will allow your plugin to work, and then if necessary you can change the encoding back afterwards using the same method. You could probably also set up a [`BufUnload`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#BufUnload) or [`BufDelete`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#BufDelete) autocommand to automatically change the encoding back when you are done with the buffer.

However, note that changing the encoding is not necessarily a reversible operation, and it's possible that changing it to a new encoding and then back again will result in data loss.

You also ask in the comments about setting a fallback option. This is what the [`'fileencodings'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27fileencodings%27) option (plural, with an `s`!) is used for. Setting it to e.g.:

```
:set fileencodings=big5,utf-8
```

will instruct Vim first to try reading files with big5, and if that fails, try utf-8 next. You can add as many comma separated encodings as you like to the setting; if none of these succeed without error, Vim will use the value of [`'encoding'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27encoding%27) for reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following instruction to reload the current file without reopen in VIM.
:e ++enc=

++enc will affect the "fileencoding" variable, but "encoding“ variable.